# How to implement a factory pattern based on argument types?

Tags: c#, factory-pattern

I have `PhotoBase` class

```
public abstract class PhotoBase
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

And I have multiple derived classes, for example the path may indicate a location in the file system or an external url.

```
public class FilePhoto : PhotoBase {}

public class ExternalPhoto : PhotoBase {}
```

I want to load these photos, I have a `PhotoLoader` class like below:

```
public class PhotoLoader
{
    public void Load(FilePhoto Photo)
    {
        // get the photo from file system
    }

    public void Load(ExternalPhoto Photo)
    {
        // download the photo from path
    }
}
```

Now I want to load these photos, so I have to do:

```
public class PhotoImporter
{
    private PhotoLoader _photoLoader;

    public PhotoImporter(PhotoLoader photoLoader)
    {
        _photoLoader = photoLoader;
    }

    public void ImportPhoto(PhotoBase photo)
    {
        if (photo is FilePhoto)
        {
            _photoLoader.Load(photo as FilePhoto);
        }

        if (photo is ExternalPhoto)
        {
            _photoLoader.Load(photo as ExternalPhoto);
        }
    }
}
```

I have several derived classes and I may add more photo types in the future. Is there a more elegant way that I could get rid of `if` conditions? Using factory pattern?

Comment: Just a very basic idea: if FilePhoto, ExternalPhoto etc etc have a public property phototype, then you could have in PhotoImporter a set containing all the PhotoLoaders, with the phototype as key: then the call would just be something like _photoloader.loaders[photo.type](photo)

Comment: Another approach would be to have an abstract method `Load` on `PhotoBase`, that's then implemented by each subclass. That way, you benefit from polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your `ImportPhoto`by using pattern matching:

```
public void ImportPhoto(photoBase photo)
{
    switch(photo)
    {
        case FilePhoto filePhoto:
            loader.Load(filePhoto);
            break;
        case ExternalPhoto externalPhoto:
            loader.Load(externalPhoto);
            break;
    }
}
```

But this is only syntactic sugar and doesn't solve your real problem. What might help is a abstract `Load` method in your base class:

```
public abstract class PhotoBase
{
    public string Path { get; set; }

    public abstract void Load();
}
```

You have to implement this method in your child classes. If you call the method, the correct implementation will be chosen.

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/LfkxBQ

Comment: Thanks, but you code does not show the initialization of `loader`. Also DDD recommends that entities (such as `PhotoBase`) should not have dependency on infrastructure (because it pulls us away from SRP), by including `Load` in `PhotoBase` we are not following this recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to have an abstract method Load on PhotoBase, that's then implemented by each subclass:

```cs
public abstract class PhotoBase
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public abstract void Load();
}

public class FilePhoto : PhotoBase
{
    public override void Load()
    {
         // load from file system
    }
}

public class ExternalPhoto : PhotoBase
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        // load from path
    }
}
```

That way, you can simply call the `Load` method on a `PhotoBase`:

```cs
public class PhotoImporter
{
  public void ImportPhoto(PhotoBase photo)
  {
    photo.Load();
  }
}
```

The main advantage is that each subclass implements the `Load` method, and therefore you can add as many subclasses as you want, without worrying about forgetting to implement it.

The main drawback to this implementation is that the `Load` methods can't depend on other dependencies. So for example, if one day you need to load a photo from a database, you can't pass the DBContext.

Comment: Thanks but DDD recommends that entities (such as PhotoBase) should not have dependency on infrastructure... This would pull you away from SRP, in otherwords your entities are doing too much.

Answer (score 0):

Proper to way to implement it which will make code easy to maintain is as follows:

```
public abstract class PhotoBase
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public abstract void Load();  // Have a abtract method
}

public class FilePhoto : PhotoBase {
    public override void Load() { // Implement the abtract method
        Console.WriteLine("FilePhoto");
    }   
}

public class ExternalPhoto : PhotoBase {
    public override void Load() { // // Implement the abtract method
        Console.WriteLine("ExternalPhoto");
    }
}

public class PhotoLoader
{
    private PhotoBase _PhotoBase;
    public PhotoLoader(PhotoBase photoBase) { // Resolved by Dependency Injection
        _PhotoBase = photoBase;
    }
    public void Load()
    {
        _PhotoBase.Load();
    }
}

public class PhotoImporter
{
    private PhotoLoader _photoLoader;

    public PhotoImporter(PhotoLoader photoLoader) // Resolved by Dependency Injection
    {
        _photoLoader = photoLoader;
    }

    public void ImportPhoto()
    {
        _photoLoader.Load();
    }
}
```

You need to have Dependency Injection define so that specified implementation will get resolved and appropriate 'Load' method will be invoked.

```
void Main()
{
    // Following dependency should be resolved by Dependency Injection
    PhotoBase filePhotoBase = new FilePhoto();
    PhotoLoader filePhotoLoader = new PhotoLoader(filePhotoBase);
    PhotoImporter  filePhotoImporter = new PhotoImporter(filePhotoLoader);
    
    PhotoBase externalPhotoBase = new ExternalPhoto();
    PhotoLoader externalPhotoLoader = new PhotoLoader(externalPhotoBase);
    PhotoImporter  externalPhotoImporter = new PhotoImporter(externalPhotoLoader);
    
    
    filePhotoImporter.ImportPhoto(); // Shows output 'FilePhoto'

    externalPhotoImporter.ImportPhoto(); // Shows output 'ExternalPhoto'
}
```

You can have as much implementation as you want, but you need to have proper instance of `PhotoImporter` by Dependency Injection. Everything else will work smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I could do this:

```
public class PhotoImporter
{
    private PhotoLoader _photoLoader;

    public PhotoImporter(PhotoLoader photoLoader)
    {
        _photoLoader = photoLoader;
    }

    public void ImportPhoto(PhotoBase photo)
    {
        var childType = photo.GetType();
        dynamic childPhoto = Convert.ChangeType(photo, childType);
        _photoLoader.Load(childPhoto);
    }
}
```